# Attempting to write a few lines of code to create a master date lookup table

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Evening Chaps, hopefully, this question is better than my first one earlier this year which got -7! (of which I was actually grateful as it helped highlight my ignorance)

What I'm trying to achieve is to write a cunning line of code, that I can call in *any* dataframe I work in to get the correct week number or day of week.

for now, please consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

days = pd.date_range('01/01/2018', '01/04/2019', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days})
print(df.head(5))
    Date
0   2018-01-01
1   2018-01-02
2   2018-01-03
3   2018-01-04
4   2018-01-05
```

Now, I want to create a company week number by using the following line of code:

please note that my company uses financial calender so April is Week 1 but day 1 is a Saturday (the astute amongst you have probably know my issue already)! so for 2018, the 31/03/18 is actually my Day 1 Week 1 Financial Year 2019 as its a Saturday and we can only have 53 max Weeks.

```
df['Week'] = np.where(df['Date'].dt.month >= 4, (df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=2)).dt.week - 13,
                   (df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=2)).dt.week + 39)
print(df)


    Date        Week
0   2018-01-31  44
1   2018-02-01  44
2   2018-02-02  44
```

all good so far right?

so let us inspect December

```
dec = df.Date.dt.month == 12
print(df.loc[dec].tail(5))
    Date    Week
330 2018-12-27  39
331 2018-12-28  39
332 2018-12-29  -12
333 2018-12-30  -12
334 2018-12-31  -12
```

The issue, if I understand this is that the pd.Timedelta is attempting to correctly place my week number but because of my initial formula of `month >= 4` it gets placed as -12

additionally, March the 31 should be in Week 1 and not Week 53 as its a Saturday.

assuming that this is a very common task that many people may have worked on, does anyone have a method or manner to deal with this in a pythonic manner.

my own solution in my head is to manually create a dataframe and fix the Week, Day and Fisical Years manually, place in a noSQL or SQL dB and call that in each dF and merge the Week Number into my reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, make use of `fiscalyear` as input for your range;

```
from fiscalyear import *

a = fiscalyear.FiscalYear(2018)

fiscalyear.START_MONTH = 4

days = pd.date_range(a.start, a.end, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days})
```

Then use the code you wrote yourself for assigning weeknumbers;

```
df['Week'] = np.where(df['Date'].dt.month >= 4, (df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=2)).dt.week - 13,
                   (df['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=2)).dt.week + 39)
```

Only way I can think of is changing the values of those three days at the end of december;

```
df['Week'] = np.where(df['Week'] <= 0, 40, df['Week'])

print(df.iloc[270:280])

          Date  Week
270 2018-12-27    39
271 2018-12-28    39
272 2018-12-29    40
273 2018-12-30    40
274 2018-12-31    40
275 2019-01-01    40
276 2019-01-02    40
277 2019-01-03    40
278 2019-01-04    40
279 2019-01-05    41
```

Note; regarding the week numbers for 30 and 31 march I would do the same:

```
df['Week'] = np.where(df['Week'] > 52, 1, df['Week'])

print(df.iloc[358:365])

          Date  Week
358 2019-03-25    52
359 2019-03-26    52
360 2019-03-27    52
361 2019-03-28    52
362 2019-03-29    52
363 2019-03-30     1
364 2019-03-31     1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this gets me close but it doesn't give me the elegance I was after. I went with my own initial suggestion of creating a master file that I merge from a SQL dB, a few extra lines of code but it's okay, at least the data is correct! I'll green tick as it does what i asked on the tin.